# Setting CNAME - doesn't like the period at the end

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I created a CNAME record with the period at the end. I use bulk register and this is for the domain windward.net.

[image]

But when I go to the url http://wiki.windward.net it takes me to http://wikitoohana.azurewebsites.net. (not trailing period).

All my other CNAME records have a trailing period with no problem. Any idea why this is an issue?

Comment: "it takes you" meaning your application isn't configured for the custom hostname and you get a 30X redirect code

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Comment: The CNAME record looks correct in the DNS. On visiting your URL, though, I see an Azure 404 page, not your wiki's "hi, we're redirecting you to yet another URL" page. If that's what you want, you need to finish [setting up the mapping in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain).

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue with your DNS record.  All dns record have a trailing dot which is omitted when visiting the website. See [RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034).  Your issue is the bindings/host records on your web app.  I am not sure how you change bindings on Azure but in iis it looks like the following:
[image: IIS]